# Several complex variables tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, tag-wikis

I saw the following question, [Sources on Several Complex Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112237/sources-on-several-complex-variables), and given the tag wiki:

> The theory of functions of one complex variable with an emphasis on the theory of complex analytic functions of one complex variables

I figure perhaps there should be another tag for several complex variables? Or instead, maybe the complex variables tag should not be a 'synonym' for complex analysis with the wiki stating so explicitly the focus is on a single complex variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW, rather than repurposing (complex-variables), I would prefer creating (several-complex-variables) (I think that fits the length limit). There would probably be a bit fewer questions on that topic than on just complex analysis, so giving it a longer and more descriptive name *may* (I hope) help prevent mistags.

Comment: Fair enough. I made the new tag, and also gave it a small tag wiki. As it's an area I'll be spending a lot of time with in the future, I may be able to help keep things tagged appropriately in case of mistags too.

Comment: ..also, just took a few quick searches, and applied the tag to *all* two posts I found, dealing with several complex variables specifically. Guess I'll have to start asking questions to make the tag seem more popular..!

Comment: Thanks for the work. I'm editing the tag wiki a bit.